# In which directory does module-info.java go?

Tags: java, java-module, module-path

From the quick start tutorial of project [Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start), it seems that module-info.java goes to a directory with the name of the module, for instance, for a module my.module containing a class MyClass:

```
bin/
    my.module/
        module-info.class
        my/
            module/
                MyClass.class
```

Then, still following the tutorial, when calling MyClass (supposing it has a `method`), the module-path option is given the `bin` directory:

```
java -p path/to/bin -m my.module/my.module.MyClass
```

So far, so good.

However, it works also if I write:

```
java -p path/to/bin/my.module -m my.module/my.module.MyClass
```

And I don't understand why both work.

It makes no difference if `bin` contains two modules: if both directories are in module path, the second version still works (and if only `bin` is in module path, it works too, as documented in the tutorial).

---

Now, when I try to create a Maven project with Eclipse, using Java 9 modules, the module-info.java resides in the `src/man/java` directory, and likewise module-info.class is in `target/classes`. So now the directory containing the module-info.class file has no relation with the name of the module.

And `target/classes` is also in the module path (when I check the build configuration). That's similar to the second case above, with `java -p path/to/bin/my.module -m my.module/my.module.MyClass`.
So, apparently, Java uses only the contents of module-info.class to discover the module name, and the directory name is arbitrary?

But then, in the first case, when I write `java -p path/to/bin -m my.module/my.module.MyClass`, it means Java will look in directories inside the directory in the module path.

I feel I am missing something important. Is there a clear explanation of the way Java looks for modules in directories in the module path? And what really specifies a module? (my impression is: not the directory, only module-info.java).

---

To add to my confusion: [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html) states that:

> --module-path modulepath... or -p modulepath
>
> A semicolon (;) separated list of directories in which each directory is a directory of modules.

But apparently it's not all the story, and at least it's not how Eclipse uses with this option.

---

Note: I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061428/where-to-place-module-info-java-using-java-9), but it doesn't really help: one answer says module-info.java goes in src/java/, another says it goes to a directory whose name is the module name. Apparently both are correct, but they don't explain why, and there is an apparent contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`java.lang.module.ModuleFinder#of(Path...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of(java.nio.file.Path...)):

> Returns a module finder that locates modules on the file system by searching a sequence of directories and/or packaged modules. Each element in the given array is one of:
>
> 1. A path to a directory of modules.
> 2. A path to the *top-level* directory of an *exploded module*.
> 3. A path to a *packaged module*.
>
> The module finder locates modules by searching each directory, exploded module, or packaged module in array index order. It finds the first occurrence of a module with a given name and ignores other modules of that name that appear later in the sequence.
>
> **If an element is a path to a directory of modules then each entry in the directory is a packaged module or the top-level directory of an exploded module** [emphasis added]. It is an error if a directory contains more than one module with the same name. **If an element is a path to a directory, and that directory contains a file named `module-info.class`, then the directory is treated as an exploded module rather than a directory of modules** [emphasis added].
>
> The module finder returned by this method supports modules packaged as JAR files. A JAR file with a `module-info.class` in its top-level directory, or in a versioned entry in a [multi-release](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#isMultiRelease()) JAR file, is a modular JAR file and thus defines an explicit module. [...]
>
> [...]

- When you use `--module-path path/to/bin` the path entry is treated as a *directory of modules*. This is because there is no `module-info.class` file present in the `bin` directory (i.e. top-level directory).

  - As far as I can tell, there's no requirement that any *exploded module* within the *directory of modules* needs to have a top-level directory whose name matches the name of the module. It's simply a convention. In other words, you could rename your `my.module` directory to anything you want; the `ModuleFinder` simply looks at the directory to see if there's a `module-info.class` file present.
- When you use `--module-path path/to/bin/my.module` the path entry is treated as an *exploded module*. This is because there is  a `module-info.class` file present in the `my.module` directory (i.e. top-level directory).

  - The same is true when using a build tool such as Maven. The `target/classes` directory is an *exploded module* because the `module-info.class` file is present in the top-level directory.

Unfortunately I was unable to find anything stating the above `ModuleFinder` implementation is guaranteed to be used internally when executing `java`. However, in all likelihood the above is what's used.